# How to display a viewbag while validating user input in ASP.NET MVC post controller?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

When I submit the form with the correct or incorrect answers without

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid) { return View(); }
```

I can see the viewbag but it does not validate the user input. Once I include the if statement it makes sure all the inputs are correct but it does not show me the viewbag and it does not clear the user input.

My controller methods:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Contact()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Contact(SendMail sendMail)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    { 
        return View(); 
    }

    string name = sendMail.Name;
    string lastName = sendMail.LastName;
  
    ViewBag.Message = "Thank you " + name + " for contacting New Origin Construction. We'll get back to you within 24 hours." ; 

    ModelState.Clear(); 

    return View();
}
```

Part of my view:

```
@{
    if (ViewBag.Message != null)
    {
        <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
            <span>
                @ViewBag.Message
            </span>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" label="close"></button>
        </div>
        
    }
}
```

Comment: if the user does not enter the correct input and submits the form I want what he wrote to stay there.

Comment: Is this for **ASP.NET MVC** (the "old", full, legacy, Windows-only version) - or is it for ASP.NET **Core** MVC (new, cross-platform version) - you've tagged both - please be clear about which version you're working with!

Comment: You didn't pass the model to the view. Use `return View(new SendMail())` in HTTPGET and `return View(sendMail)` in HTTPPOST

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code but works well. You can reference is there any difference.
Controller same as yours and include if statement.
SendMail.cs

```
    public class SendMail
    {
        [RegularExpression(@"^[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z\s]*$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid character")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [RegularExpression(@"^[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z\s]*$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid character")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
```

Contact.cshtml

```
@model SendMail
@{
    if (ViewBag.Message != null)
    {
        <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
            <span>
                @ViewBag.Message
            </span>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" label="close"></button>
        </div>

    }
}

<form method="post">
    <input asp-for="Name" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
    <input asp-for="LastName" />
    <span asp-validation-for="LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Test
[image]
[image]